# Get function annotations in the 'readable' format

Tags: python, reflection, annotations

When inspecting at runtime the annotations of a function, one can get the `class` annotated for a given argument. For example:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.signature(f).parameters['a'].annotation
<class 'int'>
```

The same can be achieved by doing `f.__annotations__`.

However, for reasons I will spare the reader, I would like to get the annotation in readable text format. For example: `a: int` will be retrieved as `int`, not as `<class 'int'>`.
Assume the text should be legal as input to `eval`.

I know I can do:

```
>>> str(inspect.signature(f).parameters['a'])
'a:int'
```

And then process this string using `.split` and such. But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `annotation` attribute of each parameter object is a class object, so you can simply use the `__name__` attribute of the class object to obtain the class name as a string:

```
import inspect

def f(a: int):
    pass

print(inspect.signature(f).parameters['a'].annotation.__name__)
```

This outputs:

```
int
```

But as @chepner pointed out, the `annotation` attribute can be a string if it's a forward reference, so if you want your code to be generic, you would have to take that into account. For example:

```
class A:
    def f(self, a: 'A'):
        pass

annotation = inspect.signature(A.f).parameters['a'].annotation
print(annotation.__name__ if isinstance(annotation, type) else annotation)
```

This outputs:

```
A
```

Comment: An annotation is *usually*, but not guaranteed to be, a type. It might be a forward reference, in which case it is already a string.

Comment: You are my hero. Was looking exactly for that but couldn't find it, because I was searching in `dir(int)` and it wasn't there. Is this because `__name__` belongs to a superclass of `int`? Do you have advice of a better way of looking in the future?

Comment: @AvivCohn Yes, this is because the `__name__` attribute belongs to the `object` class, the super-class of all classes in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `annotations` feature from the `__future__` module.

```
>>> from __future__ import annotations
>>> def f(x:int): pass
...
>>> f.__annotations__
{'x': 'int'}
```

This, however, was not introduced until Python 3.7.  See [PEP-563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) for more information.